# How to delete a service application in SharePoint 2013 which gives error?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, project-server

I want to delete project server 2013 service application but it give error

When I delete it from central administration it give blow error:

```
Sorry, something went wrong 

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and I tried to remove it using powershell it give blow error

my commands:

```
$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "Project Service Application"

Remove-SPServiceApplication $spapp -RemoveData
```

and the error I get:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

can anyone tell me how can I overcome this problem

Comment: Please check ULS logs, maybe you will find a call stack for the error, that give you more details.

Comment: I checked but could not find any solution, one error was null reference exception

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete PWA site collection before? Maybe something was deleted incorrectly, thats why service application now is orphaned.
Hope this article helps you to find reason: 
http://epmsource.com/2011/05/31/common-errors-when-a-pwa-site-is-deleted-incorrectly/

Comment: I already checked this site but his solution is not working for me maybe his solution is good for 2010 but my Project server is 2013 and SharePoint server is also 2013

Comment: you can restart the server once and recycle your application pool from PowerShell and and perform iisreset. also, the sql service from the sql server should also be restarted from services.msc. even after these steps,nothing is aworking then you can perform the running the central admin config wizard once again.This will flush out the corrupted files and unwanted cache files from the file system and SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

Open your IIS and check the Application Pool which is hosting your Project Server Web Application. Is this App pool running?

The account that you are using to delete the Project Server web application has the rights in the hosting application pool?

Also check if SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool is running and the account has right permissions.

Try resetting the SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool and then perform an IIS reset and then try deleting your web application.